# In Spring Junit test how can I test cascade operation with default rollback=true

Tags: java, spring, junit

This is a my sample test case in which A has One-to-Many relationship with B. Now I add an Instance of B to the List of Bs A and perform a SaveOrUpdate on instance of A but the test case fails when rollback is true since ID for the instance of B is not generated.
It passes when Rollback is false, but then an entry also gets added to the database.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager",defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class Test1 {

    @Autowired
    DummyDao dummyDao;
    @Test
//  @Rollback(false)
    public void newTest2(){
        //      A temp=dummyDao.getAById(new Long(1));
        A temp=dummyDao.getAs().get(0);
        Hibernate.initialize(temp.getBs());
    B class2=new B();
    temp.getBs().add(class2);
    dummyDao.saveA(temp);
    assertNotNull(class2.getId());
}
}
```

Details of Class A

```
import java.util.List;  
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn;
@Table(name="UJJWAL_DUMMY", schema="dbo")
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column
private String prop;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="fk_A")
@IndexColumn(name="idx")
private List<B> Bs;
// Setter and getters
}
```

Details of Class B
    @Entity
    public class B {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private Long id;

@Column
private String dummyColumn2;
// Setters and Getters
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you call `Hibernate.initialize()`?

Comment: The test looks correct at first glance. Rollback has no effect on generating IDs for instances. Please show the relevant parts of `A` and `B`.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla I used Hibernate.initialize() because the relation ship is Lazy and the id gets generated for the temp(A's instance) but not for class2(B's instance) when rollback is enabled.

Comment: Sorry, can't see any problem. I would expect the code above to work :-/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manually flush changes to database before checking the ids value? If id is generated in database, a flush is needed before it is set. `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` usually defaults to column of type identity which is auto number generated in database.